# Python class, data structure and proper architecture

Tags: python, import, architecture

I'm writing a program, which request user information from different services, puts them together in some ways. manages stuff and does some slack interaction.
All my python projects get problematic at a certain size. imports start to become recursive and handling data around becomes annoying.

A quick example of a problem I just come across can be shown with this simple example. I have a main module (here A) which creates the main objects (singletons).
These objects need to call functions from each other, so I use main as a connector. In this given example I don't understand when B is created the list that it requests from A is (None) NoneType. The getter function is not necessarily the way I go, but it helped in another situation. Do you have any tips, reads to point, how to structure middle-sized python programs. Thanks!

```
import B

some_list = None
b = None

def get_list():
    return some_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_list = [1,2,3]
    b = B.B()
    print b.my_list
```

And module B

```
from A import get_list

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = get_list().map(lambda v : v * 2) # CRASH HERE!
```

Answer (score 3):

You have **two** copies of the main module now, each a separate entry in `sys.modules`:

1. The initial Python script, started from the command-line, is always called `__main__`.
2. You imported the `A.py` file as the `A` module. This is **separate** from the `__main__` module.

Yes, the same source file provided both modules, but Python sees them as distinct.

As a result, that second copy does not have the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block executed, because the `__name__` variable is set to `'A'` instead. As such, `A.some_list` and `A.b` remain set to `None`; you wanted `__main__.some_list` and `__main__.b` instead.

Don't put code in your main entry point that other modules need to import to have access to. *Pass in such dependencies*, or have them managed by a separate module that both the main module and other modules can import.

You could, for example, pass in the function to the `B()` class:

```
b = B.B(get_list)
```

Comment: mmh not sure if its a version thing (2.7.11) but I can't use `__main__` for: `NameError: global name '__main__' is not defined`..

Comment: @ramin: This is not a Python version thing. You didn't import `__main__`.

Comment: even tho pycharm complains about not finding __main __ to import it works - after fixing the map fct :D  thanks!

Comment: @ramin: you really want to avoid importing from `__main__` however.